# how can I flatMap a stream that has a map returning a List?

Tags: java

I havent done something like this and I am not really sure why its not working.

SO I have something like this:

```
List<String> names = students.stream()
            .map(StudentService::getNamesCode) // this returns a String
            .flatMap(value -> StudentService::getInfo) // this returns a List<String> for each entry
            .map(// do something else)
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is it possible? I am pretty sure Im doing something wrong, on the flatMap I should send a streamable element, in this case a list should do the job.

I also tried `Stream.of(StudentService::getInfo)` but no luck.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it is convert the list to a stream. But the problem of doing like this `Stream.of(StudentService::getInfo)` is that you are creating a stream with a single element that is a list.

You should use instead `StudentService.getInfo(value).stream()` so you convert the list to a stream of elements.

Your final code would be:

```
List<String> names = students.stream()
            .map(StudentService::getNamesCode) // this returns a String
            .flatMap(value -> StudentService.getInfo(value).stream()) // this returns a List<String> for each entry
            .map(// do something else)
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```